# rotate PDF 90 degrees relative to current rotation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymupdf

I have rotated a PDF using fitz by 90 degrees using this code:

```
fitz_doc = fitz.open(origin, filetype="pdf")
fitz_doc_name = f"{fitz_doc.name}.pdf"

page = fitz_doc[int(0)]
page.setRotation(90)
fitz_doc.save(fitz_doc_name)
fitz_doc.close()
```

However, if I want to rotate the document again by another 90 degrees, I have to set `page.setRotation` to 180 and not 90. I suspect this has to do with how the 3x3 Matrix values are being manipulated but not sure if that is correct or how to manipulate the values directly.

How can I rotate a document relative to the current rotation so that if a document was previously rotated by 90 I only need to set rotation value to 90 and not 180 for the second rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a direct way to do this. Instead, you get the current rotation value and then add to it how much more you want to rotate.

```
more_rot = 90  # extra rotation desired
current_rot = page.rotation
page.setRotation(current_rot + more_rot)
```